# interactive googlemap javascript api with android api

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

i want to draw some line on google map to custom traffic flow on our custom map by javascript Api dynamically and get it with android api , i want to do this but i dont know how < is it posible ?

Comment: Why would you want your traffic flow be written in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have published your custom map with custom traffic flow in a website, you might want to consider using a `webview` to load your specific webpage with your map on your android application.

In your XML file:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview_map"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

On your Activity, you can do something like:

```
Webview webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_map);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("YOUR_WEBPAGE_URL");
setContentView(webview);
```

Or you can use the available functions in [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) Here are some functions that might be able to help you in implementing your use-case:

[Add a custom/styled map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling)

[Draw Polylines and Shapes on a map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes)

Hope this helps!

Comment: there is not another way ? just web view ? no way to interactive between android api with javascript api ?

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to handle your use-case. If you are looking for a more elegant way, I think you need to programmatically implement it yourself like calling your own API in your mobile application where it gets all the updates made on your js maps. Then display it on your mobile application using Maps SDK functions.

Comment: Also, can you please add more information on your question as to what really is it that you are aiming for. Is it correct to assume that you are trying to draw on your js maps and that drawing should automatically be reflected on your map in android real-time?